# Stubbing ASP.NET Page.Form for unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, unit-testing

Fo unit testing ASP.NET controls I need a stubbed Page.

I can create an ASP.NET Page object in my unit tests by subclassing System.Web.UI.Page.
However, I cannot find a way to set Page.Form.  Adding a form with attribute (runat,server)
does not work. Overloading the form in my Subclass does not give the required functionality.

Context:
I try to unit test some homemade ASP.NET controls. These control require Page and Page.Form not to be null.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining an `IPage` and `IForm` interface that implement the needed methods and properties and create classes that implements those interfaces and wraps a `Page` or `Form` class. This way you can test the logic in those controls, without calling into the ASP.NET framework during unit testing.

**UPDATE:**

Overriding the page property will be brittle and is not advisable. Instead, you should try to minimize the amount of untestable code, by extracting logic in methods that don't depend on any ASP.NET specific (hard to test) parts. Take a look at the following example:

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    protected override override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        IPage page = new PageWrapper(this.Page);
        this.MethodToTest(page);

        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }

    internal void MethodToTest(IPage page)
    {
        // Work with IPage interface.
        if (page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

By extracting the logic out of methods that are hard to test, you can call those extracted methods directly in your tests. For instance:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MethodToTest_ScenarioToTest_ExpectedBehavior()
{
    // Arrange
    var label = new MyLabel();

    var page = new TestPage()
    {
        IsPostBack = true
    };

    // Act
    label.MethodToTest(page);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(string.Empty, label.Text);
}
```

It would be even better if you would be able to extract the code under test to it's own class and call it from your WebControl. This is however, not always possible.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The Controls I work with Inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

Comment: Our class inherits from System.Web.UI.Control and that class implements the Page property. Your suggestion would require me to override te Page Property and add a Page2 property of IPage?

Comment: I like your pagewrapper approach. Still have to make up my mind on how to make an IPage object available to my methods. I think I will use constructor Injected to a protected or private property.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to test? If what you are testing is not completely dependent on the page itself maybe you can avoid needing an instance of page entirely saving yourself a lot of heartache. Take a look at the following link:

http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html.

However, if what you are trying to test really depends on the page class wrap it with your own class that provides access methods to the data. Then turn that class into an interface to be used as a parameter to the method or to the constructor.

Example:

```
public testPageNull_shouldThrowArgumentNullException()
{
    PageWrappable nullPage = new MockPageWrappable();
    nullPage.GetPage().Return(null);

    CustomControl sut  = new CustomControl(nullPage);   

    Assert.Fail("Exception not thrown");
}

public interface PageWrappable
{
    //Gets Wrapped Page Instance
    WrappedPage GetPage();

    //GetSomethingFromTheForm
    String GetFormValue(String Key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ASP.NET a few years back, and we implemented [Fowler's «Passive View» pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html), and managed to unit test all of the logic (and left the tests of the pretty dumb views to manual testing).

Comment: That is exactly what I did. We use Passive views but with a controller getting name/value pairs from the view components storing that in the Model. Ofcourse time/focus did not permit for unit tests in the past. I now documented the behaviour of the controls properties with unit tests and added a test to see if the rendered html is well formed by loading the generated string into a linq XElement and see whether that gives an exception. In that part we have a hard dependency to Page.form that is actually not required. I am going to solve it using something like Steven's solution.